# Delay in show after 2 second by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want if user moved the mouse for two seconds (Keep the mouse button for two seconds) on a class, show to he hide class. how is it? ()

If you move the mouse tandem (several times) on class, You will see slideToggle done as automated, I do not want this. How can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tD8hc/

My tried:

```
$('.clientele-logoindex').live('mouseenter', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.clientele_mess').slideToggle("slow");
    }, 2000 );
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.clientele_mess').slideUp("slow");
})​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below link Your Problem will solve

```
http://jsfiddle.net/G3dk3/1/
```

> var s;
>    $('.clientele-logoindex').live('mouseenter', function() {
>
> ```
>     s = setTimeout(function(){
>         $('.clientele_mess').slideDown();
>     }, 2000 );
> }).live('mouseleave', function() {
>         $('.clientele_mess').slideUp("slow");
>     clearTimeout(s)
> })
> ```

Comment: Post your answer here instead of just on a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Write your html like this

```
<div class="clientele-logoindex">Keep the mouse here
<div class="clientele_mess" style="display: none;">okkkkkkko</div></div>
```

Comment: It have problem in slideToggle done as automated after several times move the mouse on class `clientele-logoindex`. how can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Record when a timer is started and check if one exists before starting a new one:

```
window.timer = null;    
$('.clientele-logoindex').live('mouseenter', function() {
    if(!window.timer) {
        window.timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.clientele_mess').slideToggle("slow");
            window.timer = null;
        }, 2000 );
    }
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.clientele_mess').slideUp("slow");
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) is a jquery plugin to ensure hover on elements.